# Setting AMP Access Control Allow Source Origin header in Java

Tags: java, html, spring, cors, amp-html

I have an application implemented in Java(Spring) that is being called as POST method from a AMP page. Sometimes I get success message without an error and sometimes I get this error

```
"[amp-form]" "Form submission failed: Error: Response must contain the AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header​​​"
```

In my Java application, I already tried to add 'AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin header' like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/contact-amp", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
@CrossOrigin(allowedHeaders = {"Access-Control-Allow-Origin *", "AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin *", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: AMP-Access-Control-Allow-Source-Origin *"})
public SendInformationRequestV3Response saveAmp(@ModelAttribute SendInformationRequestV3 info) {
    return repository.getSendInformationRequestV3Response(info);
}
```

but I'm not sure if it's the right way. I didn't set anything in AMP side for the header. I already checked the 'CORS Requests in AMP
' documentation but didn't help me. Any ideas&suggestions to solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

You can add extension in you browser if you are using chrome for web application.
Extension : Allow-control-allow-origin